# Handling image button click inside a RecycleView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a button inside CardView which represents item of RecycleView. I've managed to handle the click event inside the ViewHolder class but I need to call function on MainActivity, How can I implement that with below code?

My code as below

> ```
> ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java
> ```

```
public class ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ListItemViewHolder> {

            static ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> list;
            LayoutInflater inflater;

            public ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> list, Context context){
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.list = list;
            }



            public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent , false);
                ListItemViewHolder vh = new ListItemViewHolder(view);
                return vh;

            }

            public void onBindViewHolder(ListItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
                ShopListItemModel current = list.get(position);
                holder.name.setText(current.getName());
                holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(current.getPrice()));

            }

            public int getItemCount() {
                return list.size();
            }

            public static class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
                CardView cv;
                TextView name;
                TextView price;
                ImageButton btnDelete;

                ListItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);

                    cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvShopListItem);
                    name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                    btnDelete = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteItem);

                    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //here i can handle the click but i think i need to use it in the main activity
                }
            }
        }
```

> MainActivity.java (skipped irrelevent code)

```
 public class ShopCartScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    RecyclerView cartItems; //recycler to hold the cart list
    ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> list = new ArrayList<ShopListItemModel>();
    ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    GetShopingCartList getShopingCartList; ////instance of network operation class to retrieve shop cart items list from server data base

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.shop_carts_list);
            cartItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.newListItem);
            cartItems.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            cartItems.setLayoutManager(llm)
    }

           public void bindData(int listNumber) {
           getShopingCartList = new GetShopingCartList(this, list, adapter, cartItems, listNumber, totalPrice);
            getShopingCartList.execute("link to query which returns json object");
            }
    }
```

> GetShopingCartList.java for network operation

```
public class GetShopingCartList extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<ShopListItemModel>> {

            private ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> shopCartItemList;
            Context context;
            RecyclerView items;
            ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
            int listNumber;

           public GetShopingCartList(Context context,   ArrayList<ShopListItemModel>    shopCartItemList, ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter,
                                      RecyclerView items ,int listNumber) {
                this.context = context;
                this.shopCartItemList = shopCartItemList;
                this.adapter = adapter;
                this.items = items;
                this.listNumber = listNumber;    
            }
        protected ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                shopCartItemList = new ArrayList<ShopListItemModel>();
        try {
                    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);

                    }
                    String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("result");
        for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);//get the cuttent json object which is representaion of shop cart model object

                        String name = finalObject.getString("name");
                        String price = finalObject.getString("price");
                        Double d = Double.parseDouble(price);
                        ShopListItemModel item = new ShopListItemModel(name, d);
                         shopCartItemList.add(item);//adds the shopcart to the list of shop carts model

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                    try {
                        if (reader != null) {
                            reader.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
                return shopCartItemList;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                adapter = new ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter(shopCartItemList, context);
                items.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
                 public ArrayList<ShopListItemModel> getList() {
                return shopCartItemList;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can use local Broadcast receiver for this.. Make a Broadcast in `onClick()` from adapter and receive it in your **Activity**. I can give a example if you wish to implement..!!

Comment: im pretty new to android development, ill be happy to an example with explanations if your ok with that. i also never implemented broad cast receiver at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a method inside ShopCartScreen.java, then you can use the `context` object inside the adapter.

```
    ((ShopCartScreen)context).methodImplemented(ShopListItemModel model)
    //add this code inside onClick event of the button
```

Comment: i`ve implemented it like this. main activity:                                          public void deleteItem(int postion){
list = getShopingCartList.getList();
list.remove(postion);
adapter = new ShopItemRecyclerViewAdapter(list, this);
cartItems.setAdapter(adapter);
}   it working but ofcourse this way the delete animation doesn`t work, you hava a solution?

Comment: the button Onclick in the viewHolder:                                                              public void onClick(View v) {
            //here i can handle the click but i think i need to use it in the main activity
            ((ShopCartScreen)context).deleteItem(getPosition());

        }    also the getPosition is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

ok this is my solution if anyone needs it (i combined 2 methods/ 1 in the main activity and 1 in the recycler adapter):

in my recycler adapter i added this delete method:

```
//delete the item from the recycler Immediately for user interaction
public void delete(int position){
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

in my ViewHolder class:

```
ListItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvShopListItem);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            btnDelete = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteItem);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ShopCartScreen)context).deleteItem(getPosition());//calls method in main activity
            delete(getPosition());
        }
```

and in the main activity:

```
public void deleteItem(int postion){
            list = getShopingCartList.getList();
            ShopListItemModel tmp = list.get(postion);
            tmp.getName(); //gets the item name to remove
            shopCartModel.getNumber(); //gets the cart number for deleting the item for the correct cart
            new DeleteCartItem(this , shopCartModel , tmp).execute(); //remove the item from the data base
        }
```